# Make LaTeX / KOMA-Script ignore vertical depth in sections

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, koma-script, double-sided

How can I force LaTeX / KOMA-Script (>=3.15) to ignore the vertical depth in sections?

MWE showing the problem:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section{ja}
\rule{\textwidth}{1cm}
\clearpage
\section{nein}
\rule{\textwidth}{1cm}
\end{document}
```

The box on the left side is clearly below the box on the right side. For text, this might not be the problem, but in my case, there isn't only text but pictures directly below the section and their top lines don't align in such a case.

Comment: Add struts to the section so that they all have the same depth: \section{nein\strut}.

Comment: or use `\rule[-1cm]{\textwidth}{1cm}` so the baseline of the rule is its top edge not the bottom edge,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if `LaTeX / KOMA-Script (>=3.15)` means that you can use the up to date version 3.19a too. If that is possible you can redefine `\sectionlinesformat` to insert a `\strut` at the end of all section headings.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}[2015/10/3]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4\ifhmode\unskip\strut\fi}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{ja}
\rule{\textwidth}{1cm}
\clearpage
\section{nein}
\rule{\textwidth}{1cm}
\end{document}
```